# Is there an easy way to generate test data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, testing

I want to generate test data in mysql

Assuming that there is a table like this,

```
create table person (
  id int auto_increment primary key,
  name text,
  age int,
  birth_day date
);
```

let me know how to create test data in a simple way.

BTW I know some ways using stdin like

```
repeat 5 echo 'insert into person (name, age, birth_day) select concat("user", ceil(rand() * 100)), floor(rand()*100), date_add(date("1900/01/01"), interval floor(rand()*100) year);'
```

or

```
repeat 5 perl -M"Data::Random qw(:all)" -E 'say sprintf qq#insert into person (name, age, birth_day) values ("user%s", %s,"%s");#,  (int rand(100)), (int rand(100)), rand_date(min => "1900-01-01", max=>"1999-12-31")'
```

I think the latter may be better because it doesn't use mysql functions.

Comment: Does it need to be discernible data (that is, does a name field have to be an actual name, or can it be random text?) - How about this? http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6416-PHP-Populate-a-MySQL-database-with-random-data.html

Comment: Thank your link. I will try this. Sorry to unable of understanding what you say, but I think a name field doesn't have to be an actual name. I mean the person table is an example.

Comment: That's it, if it doesn't have to be an actual name, ignore my question!

Answer (score 6):

This is the easiest way to generate dummy data for MySQL:

http://www.generatedata.com/

See also:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/449/tool-to-generate-large-datasets-of-test-data

Comment: thanks. but http://dummydata.me/generate doesn't work? and I like offline.  I will read the next link later

Comment: please let me know if it is useful to you?

Comment: I'm afraid to say what you gave me are not a small tool. I should have said I want to generate data by shell commands which I think are smaller tools than online web tools.  I hope there are something of useful command line tools that give better interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, as sysadmin, I use the library [Faker](https://pypi.org/project/Faker/) that permit to generate on-the-fly data.

for your database `person`, you could the following

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random

import mysql.connector             
from mysql.connector import Error  
from faker import Faker

Faker.seed(33422)
fake = Faker()

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host=db_host, database=db_name,
                               user=db_user, password=db_pass)
cursor = conn.cursor()
  
row = [fake.first_name(), random.randint(0,99), fake.date_of_birth()]

cursor.execute(' \                                                                          
     INSERT INTO `person` (name, age, birth_day) \ 
     VALUES ("%s", %d, "%s",);' % (row[0], row[1], row[2])

conn.commit()
```

Then you can improve the script by looping and at each iteration `faker` will create random `name` and `birth_date`.
Faker has an extended list of type (called "provider") of data it can generate, the full list is available at https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://paulthedutchman.nl/datagenerator-online. Also available as offline version to use on your local development environment. It has so much more options than other datagenerators out there.
Not suitable for mobile devices because it uses ExtJS, use it on your computer.

The offline version automatically scans your database and table structure.

Answer (score 0):

This [random data generator](https://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/generate-random-test-data-for-mysql-using-routines) for MySQL is based on mysql routines and you don't need to really provide anything other than database and table names.

To use it:

- Download the routines from GitHub
- mysql < populate.sql
- mysql> call populate('database','table',1000,'N');